# Select and pass datagridview row values to another form

Tags: c#, datagridview

In my application I want to select a full row in my `datagridview` and pass it to comboboxes which is located in another form. I tried it with following code but it is throwing me the error "No overload for method 'this' takes 1 arguments"

this is my code

```
if(dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
{
    var oneCell = dataGridView1[0];
    int editloannumber = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    int editlid = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString());
    string editloantype = dataGridView1.Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    string editneworsecond = dataGridView1.Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    string editpurpose = dataGridView1.Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
    string editstatus = dataGridView1.Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    string editcomments = dataGridView1.Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
    string editretail = dataGridView1.Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value.ToString();

    wartif_UW.editform e2 = new wartif_UW.editform(editloannumber, editloantype, editneworsecond, editpurpose, editstatus, editcomments, editretail,editlid);
    e2.ShowDialog();
 }
```

and this is my second form constructer

```
public editform(int editln, string edittype, string editno2, string purpo, string stat, string come,string reti,int lid)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboload();

        loannumbertxtbox.Text  = editln ;
        loantypecombobox.Text = edittype;
        loanpurposrcombo.Text = purpo;
        neworseccombobox.Text = editno2;
        retailregcombo.Text = reti;
        statuscombbox.Text = stat;
        commnetrichtext.Text = come;
    }
```

Comment: can you post editform's code?

Comment: sorry someone edit it while im updating it. i updated my question again

Comment: which line is throwing the error ..? `comboload();` your error if it's this one is expecting you to call it with at least one `Parameter` can you show what comboload looks like..?

Comment: no not the comboload error is  var oneCell = dataGridView1[0]; line

Comment: Error in the line:`var oneCell = dataGridView1[0];` `DataGridView` not a collection/indexed type. Try this: `var oneCell = datagridview.CurrentCell;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGridView does not have an indexer. You had to do something like this:

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
        {
            var oneCell = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0];
            int editloannumber = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            int editlid = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString());
            string editloantype = dataGridView1.Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            string editneworsecond = dataGridView1.Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            string editpurpose = dataGridView1.Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
            string editstatus = dataGridView1.Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            string editcomments = dataGridView1.Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            string editretail = dataGridView1.Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value.ToString();

            wartif_UW.editform e2 = new wartif_UW.editform(editloannumber, editloantype, editneworsecond, editpurpose, editstatus, editcomments, editretail, editlid);
            e2.ShowDialog();
        }
```